# @Schedule annotation and timeout in EJB bean

Tags: java, ejb, websphere, scheduled-tasks

What happens if I have @Scheduled task which runs every 5 seconds and sometimes it takes more than 5 seconds to complete this task? EJB container knows how to deal in such scenario or I need to care it by myself? 
Thank you.

P.S. My EJB bean annotated by @Startup and @Singleton, and I run it on Websphere 8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are good because you bean is annotated with `@Singleton`. 
EJB beans are synchronized unless you explicitly mark methods with `@Asynchronous`. So if a cron execution(a thread) is in progress then other cron run(another thread) will have to wait for the first one to finish.

Comment: You link bring me to Spring documentation, but I'm using EJB beans not Spring, is it apply to EJB beans also? I haven't find mention to 'fixed' on Oracle manuals.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the answer. I think you should add EJB somewhere in the title to make it more specific and easy to come up in the search result for ejb related @Scheduled.

Comment: You're right, my apologizes. I have add it to the title.